# Using setExactAndWhileIdle method for sdk 23

Tags: android, sdk, version, alarmmanager

I want to use below code for a run different method for different SDK but when I wrote `setExactAndWhileIdle` in SDK_INT 23, cannot resolve this method! I wrote my gradle in below. Please if you know, help me.

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void setAlarmForCallingSchedule(long trigger) {
     if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=23){
        alarmManager.setExactAndWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,trigger,repeatingSchedulePI);
    }else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=19){
       alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,trigger,repeatingSchedulePI);
    }else {
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,trigger, 1000 * 60 * 90, repeatingSchedulePI);
    }
}
```

My gradle:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
}
```

when I changed my buildToolsVersion to 23.0.1, I get an error , "The SDK Build Tools revision(23.0.1) is too low for the project. Minimum required is 25.0.0"